# How to handle bad request in Custom ExceptionalHandler class?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am developing ***Spring Boot JPA*** example and in this example I have developed custom `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` class with the `@ControllerAdvice`.

```
{
  "createUser": "string",
  "lastUpdateUser": "string",
  "employeeName": "John Doe",
  "employeeEmail": "john.doe@gmail.com" //line-4
  "status": "string"
}
```

If you look at the `POST` request, at line-4 I missed out to put semicolon (,) hence request is considered invalid. Now I am getting `400 HTTP` error, but I wanted to show custom error message by handling it in `ExceptionalHandler` class. Any quick help?

Answer (score 1):

**Create your own custom exception.**

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;

    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public class BadRequestException extends RuntimeException {

      public BadRequestException(String message) {
        super(message);
      }

    }
```

**Handle your custom exception in your @ControllerAdvice class**

```
@ExceptionHandler(BadRequestException.class)
  public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleException(
      BadRequestException e) {
    // improve error logging when used.
    log.error("Unexpected Bad Request. ", e);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(new ErrorResponse("Unexpected Bad Request. " + e.getMessage()),
        HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
  }
```

Comment: It means there is not an inbuild method that we can override for this issue ? We just need to provided Custom method ?

Comment: You have to throw BadRequestExpection to be handled from your main code /or controller

Comment: Even Controller is not getting called, its getting lost somewhere that I am trying to understand by debugging, but just seeing filters of spring getting called only

Answer (score 1):

You can simply implement below method. This Customize the response for `HttpMessageNotReadableException`.

```
@Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpMessageNotReadable(HttpMessageNotReadableException ex,
            HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        logger.debug("========================");
        return super.handleHttpMessageNotReadable(ex, headers, status, request);
    }
```